# Whats wrong with our two Jasmine Plants

Tags: diseases

[image]
We bought these two grown Jasmine plants 2 months ago when they had a few flowers and healthy green leaves. But now it looks like they are afflicted with some disease.

We live in Pune, India. The weather these days is like Temp: 15 to 30 deg C, Humidity: 30 to 60%. The plants have been watered regularly. They were kept outside in a place which gets diffused sunlight (shade of the apartment building) most of the day. The plants were potted by a professional, so I am thinking that he would have taken care of the roots while transplanting. We did not add anything to the plants other than watering during the last 2 months.

What could be the issue? What should I do?

PS: Yesterday, after 2 months, we added some fertilizer granules and manure yesterday and moved them to an area which receives ample direct sunlight for a longer duration. Will that help?

PPS: The plant seems to be of the species Nyctanthes elongata (a.k.a. [Jasminum elongatum](https://biodiversity.bt/species/show/5955). Here is a photo from happier times.
[image: Flowers during happier times]

Comment: There's evidence of leaf miner activity, but check underneath all the leaves, looking closely for anything else that shouldn't be there such as insects or webbing. When you say 'Jasmine', the plants in the images you've provided do not appear to be Jasminum varieties, so do you have another (especially botanical) name for your plant?

Comment: Updated what I am guessing to be the correct botanical name. I have added a photo of the flowers in case someone can confirm if it is indeed Nyctanthes elongata. Checked under the leaves, there seems to be some signs of some bugs, but they were few, not worthy of inspection. Will wait a few days to see if the disease develops further or if moving to an area with ample sunlight helps.